# Filter out/omit regions with rapid slope change

Tags: python, performance, derivative

I am trying to find the slopes of data sets but have many different type of sets. Ideally, I would have a relatively straight line with some noise where I can take the average slope and std. This plot can be seen below:

[image]

However, sometimes some datasets will have sharp jumps (because the output data has to be resized) that interfere with the averaging and std processing.

[image]
[image]

Is there a technique or method to filter out and omit these sharp spikes? I'm thinking of identifying the spikes (by their max/min peaks) and then deleting the data within a region of the spike to clean up the data.

Not much code to show for these but I am using T for time, Y for the output data, and dYdT for the slope and graphing them.

```
plt.semilogy(T,Y)
plt.title('CUT QiES')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
                        
plt.semilogy(T,dYdT)
plt.title('Slope')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()                

print('average slope:', np.average(dYdT))
print('std slope:', np.std(dYdT))
```

Here is an example dataset for T, Y, and dYdT

```
T = [2.34354 2.34632 2.3491  2.35188 2.35466 2.35744 2.36022 2.363   2.36578
 2.36856 2.37134 2.37412 2.3769  2.37968 2.38246 2.38524 2.38802 2.3908
 2.39358 2.39636 2.39914 2.40192 2.4047  2.40748 2.41026 2.41304 2.41582
 2.4186  2.42138 2.42416 2.42694 2.42972 2.4325  2.43528 2.43806 2.44084
 2.44362 2.4464  2.44918 2.45196 2.45474 2.45752 2.4603  2.46308 2.46586
 2.46864 2.47142 2.4742  2.47698 2.47976 2.48254 2.48532 2.4881  2.49088
 2.49366 2.49644 2.49922 2.502   2.50478 2.50756 2.51034 2.51312 2.5159
 2.51868 2.52146 2.52424 2.52702 2.5298  2.53258 2.53536 2.53814 2.54092
 2.5437  2.54648 2.54926 2.55204 2.55482 2.5576  2.56038 2.56316 2.56594
 2.56872 2.5715  2.57428 2.57706 2.57984 2.58262 2.5854  2.58818 2.59096
 2.59374 2.59652 2.5993  2.60208 2.60486 2.60764 2.61042 2.6132  2.61598
 2.61876 2.62154 2.62432 2.6271  2.62988 2.63266 2.63544 2.63822 2.641
 2.64378 2.64656 2.64934 2.65212 2.6549  2.65768 2.66046 2.66324 2.66602
 2.6688  2.67158 2.67436 2.67714 2.67992 2.6827  2.68548 2.68826 2.69104
 2.69382 2.6966  2.69938 2.70216 2.70494 2.70772 2.7105  2.71328 2.71606
 2.71884 2.72162 2.7244  2.72718 2.72996 2.73274 2.73552 2.7383  2.74108
 2.74386 2.74664 2.74942 2.7522  2.75498 2.75776 2.76054 2.76332 2.7661
 2.76888 2.77166 2.77444 2.77722 2.78    2.78278 2.78556 2.78834 2.79112
 2.7939  2.79668 2.79946 2.80224 2.80502 2.8078  2.81058 2.81336 2.81614
 2.81892 2.8217  2.82448 2.82726 2.83004 2.83282 2.8356  2.83838 2.84116
 2.84394 2.84672 2.8495  2.85228 2.85506 2.85784 2.86062 2.8634  2.86618
 2.86896 2.87174 2.87452 2.8773  2.88008 2.88286 2.88564 2.88842 2.8912
 2.89398 2.89676 2.89954 2.90232 2.9051  2.90788 2.91066 2.91344 2.91622
 2.919   2.92178] 

Y = [1.4490e+24 4.1187e+24 1.1708e+25 3.3279e+25 9.4596e+25 2.6889e+26
     7.6435e+26 2.1727e+27 6.1762e+27 1.7556e+28 1.6093e-01 4.5747e-01
     1.3004e+00 3.6967e+00 1.0508e+01 2.9872e+01 8.4918e+01 2.4140e+02
     6.8623e+02 1.9508e+03 5.5455e+03 1.5764e+04 4.4814e+04 1.2739e+05
     3.6214e+05 1.0295e+06 2.9265e+06 8.3192e+06 2.3649e+07 6.7227e+07
     1.9111e+08 5.4325e+08 1.5443e+09 4.3899e+09 1.2479e+10 3.5473e+10
     1.0084e+11 2.8663e+11 8.1479e+11 2.3161e+12 6.5837e+12 1.8714e+13
     5.3197e+13 1.5121e+14 4.2983e+14 1.2218e+15 3.4730e+15 9.8721e+15
     2.8062e+16 7.9766e+16 2.2674e+17 6.4450e+17 1.8320e+18 5.2075e+18
     1.4803e+19 4.2077e+19 1.1961e+20 3.3998e+20 9.6642e+20 2.7471e+21
     7.8089e+21 2.2197e+22 6.3098e+22 1.7936e+23 5.0986e+23 1.4493e+24
     4.1199e+24 1.1711e+25 3.3291e+25 9.4636e+25 2.6902e+26 7.6473e+26
     2.1739e+27 6.1796e+27 1.7567e+28 1.6088e-01 4.5734e-01 1.3001e+00
     3.6957e+00 1.0506e+01 2.9864e+01 8.4893e+01 2.4132e+02 6.8600e+02
     1.9501e+03 5.5434e+03 1.5758e+04 4.4794e+04 1.2733e+05 3.6196e+05
     1.0289e+06 2.9248e+06 8.3141e+06 2.3634e+07 6.7181e+07 1.9097e+08
     5.4284e+08 1.5431e+09 4.3863e+09 1.2468e+10 3.5442e+10 1.0075e+11
     2.8638e+11 8.1404e+11 2.3140e+12 6.5776e+12 1.8697e+13 5.3148e+13
     1.5108e+14 4.2944e+14 1.2207e+15 3.4700e+15 9.8637e+15 2.8038e+16
     7.9701e+16 2.2656e+17 6.4401e+17 1.8307e+18 5.2039e+18 1.4793e+19
     4.2049e+19 1.1953e+20 3.3978e+20 9.6587e+20 2.7456e+21 7.8048e+21
     2.2186e+22 6.3068e+22 1.7928e+23 5.0963e+23 1.4487e+24 4.1181e+24
     1.1706e+25 3.3277e+25 9.4595e+25 2.6890e+26 7.6439e+26 2.1729e+27
     6.1767e+27 1.7558e+28 1.6085e-01 4.5724e-01 1.2998e+00 3.6947e+00
     1.0503e+01 2.9855e+01 8.4867e+01 2.4124e+02 6.8576e+02 1.9493e+03
     5.5412e+03 1.5751e+04 4.4775e+04 1.2728e+05 3.6179e+05 1.0284e+06
     2.9234e+06 8.3100e+06 2.3622e+07 6.7147e+07 1.9087e+08 5.4256e+08
     1.5423e+09 4.3840e+09 1.2462e+10 3.5424e+10 1.0070e+11 2.8624e+11
     8.1366e+11 2.3129e+12 6.5747e+12 1.8689e+13 5.3126e+13 1.5102e+14
     4.2928e+14 1.2203e+15 3.4688e+15 9.8604e+15 2.8029e+16 7.9677e+16
     2.2649e+17 6.4383e+17 1.8302e+18 5.2025e+18 1.4789e+19 4.2039e+19
     1.1950e+20 3.3970e+20 9.6565e+20 2.7450e+21 7.8030e+21 2.2181e+22
     6.3052e+22 1.7923e+23 5.0950e+23 1.4483e+24 4.1170e+24 1.1703e+25
     3.3267e+25 9.4566e+25 2.6882e+26 7.6414e+26 2.1721e+27 6.1745e+27
     1.7552e+28 1.6085e-01 4.5723e-01 1.2997e+00 3.6946e+00] 

dYdT = [   375.78737971    375.77838714    375.80388102    375.77489158
        375.78727498    375.78675618    375.79979331    375.79140766
        375.80307981    375.78869648 -24051.07160929    375.80641042
        375.79707901    375.81605048    375.79005109    375.82183992
        375.81456769    375.81626751    375.81206469    375.82085444
        375.80836087    375.80650046    375.82436377    375.80311386
        375.81929146    375.82649247    375.80356916    375.81256353
        375.81105553    375.81083518    375.81806689    375.79871965
        375.81165219    375.80421386    375.80603732    375.80022022
        375.8141218     375.77592917    375.80511723    375.7948217
        375.79574124    375.78237753    375.80219314    375.77971056
        375.79862682    375.78801386    375.78906206    375.78914497
        375.79271626    375.78453256    375.79375471    375.78087618
        375.78731038    375.78835536    375.80214704    375.7810828
        375.80402049    375.77350442    375.79558632    375.79229009
        375.7979493     375.78886178    375.80285205    375.79348417
        375.80619385    375.79128849    375.80870862    375.79125174
        375.81241695    375.80966301    375.80855141    375.80471369
        375.81123673    375.80242985    375.81604229 -24051.40870014
        375.81595371    375.81631899    375.80172556    375.8188996
        375.7939637     375.80499941    375.80295453    375.81071013
        375.81233977    375.80121497    375.80580644    375.80072988
        375.79422292    375.80991615    375.79562622    375.80425607
        375.8009951     375.80341171    375.79284757    375.80067561
        375.79074445    375.80361218    375.78872914    375.78392619
        375.80294807    375.80742564    375.7832372     375.78773547
        375.79978522    375.78860014    375.78890145    375.79762286
        375.80180688    375.78148795    375.79054293    375.80220477
        375.79379778    375.79114431    375.79906468    375.80132293
        375.79296526    375.80555123    375.7949414     375.80782426
        375.78471547    375.80279891    375.80250484    375.8024821
        375.80059702    375.80550314    375.79947132    375.81008995
        375.80407198    375.80436789    375.80464364    375.80046381
        375.79483415    375.81472546    375.80509096    375.80393624
        375.80523987    375.80569415    375.79908899    375.80055332
     -24051.29144699    375.80437535    375.81196702    375.78739346
        375.81351451    375.78827315    375.80323568    375.79387173
        375.80410925    375.79061168    375.80602519    375.78876673
        375.80794699    375.80555255    375.78221186    375.78976345
        375.80687988    375.79578647    375.79815551    375.79344053
        375.79436049    375.79356487    375.80266523    375.78659745
        375.79944765    375.79336058    375.81159827    375.78590649
        375.79567215    375.7967047     375.80100764    375.79358484
        375.80263853    375.80785172    375.79032673    375.80669873
        375.79567722    375.79784997    375.79602616    375.80621348
        375.79850067    375.80356916    375.80784654    375.79641323
        375.80733162    375.79643801    375.79806206    375.80809489
        375.80524264    375.80392238    375.80115114    375.80136383
        375.79989791    375.79500521    375.8129336     375.79707955
        375.80370071    375.79873252    375.79881131    375.80290963
        375.80719684    375.79460713    375.79090002    375.80340505
        375.80575394 -24051.16850348    375.79650823    375.79215864
        375.80533293]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to identify the outlier points based on using the median to find the most common data point and deleting any points outside a range from the median values. The code is as follows:

```
med = statistics.median(dYdT) #find median of dataset
perc = .05                    #cutoff threshold
med_min = med - perc*med      #min cuttof
med_max = med + perc*med      #max cutoff

#find the locations of the sharp changes
peak_loc = []
peak_loc.extend(np.where(dYdT < med_min)[0])
peak_loc.extend(np.where(dYdT > med_max)[0])

#delete the data where the peaks are located
dYdT = np.delete(dYdT, peak_loc, axis=0)
Y = np.delete(Y, peak_loc, axis=0)
T = np.delete(T, peak_loc, axis=0)
```

Here are plots showing how it deleted points with rapid varying slopes:

Example 1

[image]

Example 2

[image]

And proof that datasets that don't need cleaning are unaffected:

[image]

You can adjust the perc variable to make the cutoff move or less lax as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **median filter** to remove outliers from a signal. More specifically you can use [`medfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html) of `scipy.signal`. Here is the result of `scipy.signal.medfilt(dYdT, 3)`:

[image]

Comment: This appears to work but it changes the std of the data without the sharp peaks (such as the first example). In other words, it operates even on the data that doesn't need the cleaning. It appears the filter does a global filter of the data and I'm looking more for a local filter of the large spikes to remove them. Also what does the kernel affect and would it help? I can't find much explanation of it.